# Is this a well defined set in ZFC?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is this a well defined set in ZFC?
$$M= \lbrace (A,B) : A\subset M \land B \subset M \rbrace$$
Also is the following reasoning correct?
$$\lbrace\rbrace \subset M \Rightarrow \left(\lbrace\rbrace,\lbrace\rbrace  \right)\in M$$
I think the set M can also be defined in the following way:
$$M_{0}=\lbrace\rbrace$$
$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N_{}}:M_{n+1}=\lbrace(A,B):A\subset M_{n}\land B \subset M_{n} \rbrace$$
$$M=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}M_{n}=\lbrace x:\exists n\in\mathbb{N}:x\in M_{n}\rbrace$$

Comment: If you *define* M in this way then no, since this would require circular reasoning. On th other hand you could ask if a set M satisfying those properties exists. Right now we have two different answers to this. I do think that your construction will give an example of a set  of type M but we could also stat $M_0$ off as some nonempty set and get a bigger set of size M.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your set essentially satisfies the relation $M = \mathcal P(M)^2$. This would contradict Cantor's theorem :

Let $S = \{(A,B) \in M \mid (A,B) \notin A \}$ and let $m = (S,\emptyset)$. Then $m \in S \iff m \notin S$, which is a contradiction.

In general, $\bigcup \mathcal P(M_k) \subset \mathcal P(\bigcup M_k)$ and the inclusion is strict.

If you define $M$ as the reunion of the sets $M_n$, the $M$ obtained doesn't satisfy the equation, but you still have that $M = \bigcup \mathcal P(M_n)^2$ . There is still an inclusion $M \to \mathcal P(M)^2$. Of course the inclusion is strict since if $m \in M_n$ then its image is actually in $\mathcal P(M_{n-1})^2$. So this never reaches subsets of $M$ containing elements of arbitrarily high level.